# Render webform node on page callback with view, edit, webform, result tabs

Tags: webforms, routes

I have a setup where I direct authorized users to a profile2 page or render a webform to anonymous users, using page callback in hook_menu_alter .

I want the admins to be able to access the webform node along with the tabs on the top (view,edit,results,webform). However when I render using `node_view(node_load($nodeid))` the tabs disappear.
I have tried node_load with the "full" option as well and it does not work.

Tabs:

[image: Webform tabs]

Redirection to the webform node will result in an endless redirect loop.

How do I render the webform node along with the tabs on hook_menu_alter page callback?